# Код не возвращает Bool в положение false C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Код не возвращает Bool в false в Unity3D, подскажите как написать, надоело уже танцевать с бубном.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) {
        player.transform.position += player.transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool ("RunBack", true);
    } else { animator.SetBool("RunBack", false); }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        player.transform.position -= player.transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("RunFront", true);
    }
    else { animator.SetBool("RunRight", false); }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) {
        player.transform.position += player.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("RunRight", true);
    }
    else { animator.SetBool("RunRight", false); }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
    {
        player.transform.position -= player.transform.right * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("RunLeft", true);
    }
    else { animator.SetBool("RunLeft", false); }

}
```

}

Comment: И где не работает?

Comment: При нажатии клавиши передвижения запускается анимация, но когда клавиша отжата, анимация остается, при этом в аниматоре значение остается true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты когда копипасту делаешь, хоть проверяй, а то у тебя в клавише *S*, при нажатии делается **RunFront**, а в противном случае **RunRight**. Вот и не происходит снятие **true**

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) {
        player.transform.position -= player.transform.up * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        animator.SetBool("RunFront", true);
    }
    else { animator.SetBool("RunRight", false); }
```

p.s.
И почему вообще **RunFront** на букву *S* , может **RunBack**? а на *W* - **RunFront** ( но это не мое дело)

Comment: Когда он бежит вниз, он смотрит лицом в камеру, это 2D игра